# Compare string values with double in DataTable.Select()

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, ado.net

My datatable salary column is `string` column and user gives input value in string format, like `userInput="1000"`. But data stored in salary column is as shown in below image. How do I compare user input with data stored in data table?

[image]

My current code is

```
DataRows[] rows = dt.Select("Salary='"+userInput+"'");
```

Comment: Try{} to convert either one's type to the other, on success compare ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to avoid formatting issues you should better compare numeric values. DataTable select filter supports `Convert` function:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(string));

// test values
dt.Rows.Add("0.10000");
dt.Rows.Add(".1");
dt.Rows.Add("-.1");
dt.Rows.Add("1.1");

decimal salary;
string userInput = "0.10";
if (decimal.TryParse(userInput, out salary))
{           
    DataRow[] matchedRows = dt.Select("Convert(Salary, 'System.Decimal') = " + salary.ToString());
    foreach(var r in matchedRows)
        Console.WriteLine(r["Salary"]);
}
```

output is:

```
.1
0.10000
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use Linq-To-DataTable:

```
decimal value;
if(decimal.TryParse(userInput, out value))
{
   var filteredRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      where row.Field<decimal>("Salary") == value
                      select row;
   // if you want an array:
   DataRow[] rows = filteredRows.ToArray();
}
```

If you insist on using `DataTable.Select` you have to remove the apostrophes:

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("Salary=" + userInput);
```

But this presumes that the input value is using the english format(so f.e. not using a different decimal separator like comma that even causes a  `SyntaxErrorException`).

---

If the type of the column is actually `string` you need to parse it to double or decimal:

```
var filteredRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   where decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("Salary")) == value
                   select row;
```

But in this cae you should better fix the wrong datatype instead.

Comment: I understood OP that his`Salary` column is of type string too. So does `row.Field<decimal>` really work?

Comment: @RenéVogt: i think it's double or decimal, that's why OP's code doesn't work. If he insisted on using `DataTable.Select` he would need to remove the apostrophes like in: `dt.Select("Salary=" +userInput)`. But then it depends on the current culture if the string conversion doesn't cause another issue.